# making all the thumbnails the same size in a gallery

Tags: html, css

Any idea why I can't change the size of thumbnail photos? I want them all be the same:

```
 <h2>Book:</h2>

  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="imgur/book/2EuGD9S.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="900x900">
          <img src="imgur/book/2EuGD9S.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" height="300" width="300" />
      </a>
                                          <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption  1</figcaption>

    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="imgur/book/Cmg3qMt.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="900x900">
          <img src="imgur/book/Cmg3qMt.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" data-size="300x300" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="imgur/book/DyvInMR.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="900x900">
          <img src="imgur/book/DyvInMR.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" data-size="300x300" />
      </a>
      <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
    </figure>



  </div>
```

complete code: https://gist.github.com/monajalal/3dace3489e20e0aeeba5351a7987065a
This is what I see:
[image]

I am using this: http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM

Update:
I changed the CSS however margin-right doesn't get affected and if I make them 200x200 there will be no margin. Why is that?
[image]

```
.my-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
/*
.my-gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
*/

.my-gallery img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 150px;
}
.my-gallery figcaption {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: try setting `img` property height and width from css something like this `img{ height: 10px; width: 10px; }` and see if this works

Comment: What do you mean by size? you want height to be equal?

Comment: I want them all to be squares of say 200x200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a width/height to your figure, assign it to the image.

```
.my-gallery img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Yields the display like this:
[image]

Comment: curious if you know why some photos have a white line above the black border? https://gist.github.com/monajalal/33d69aca1326f83f59a8e476a6aa62dc here's what I see: http://imgur.com/a/FLQ0k

Comment: Yes, that's because <img> is display: inline; by default.  Change it to display: block; to remove the white area below the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the images inside of `<a>` as a `background-image` of `<a>`. And removing the `width: 150px;` of `<figure>`. Have a look at this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/rastogi_saurav/pen/XNNxLP)

Like:

CSS:

```
figure a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <a href="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_a4c2eaa0cd_o.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="1024x1024" style="background-image: url('https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2567/5697107145_3c27ff3cd1_m.jpg')">
  </a>
  <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption  1</figcaption>  
</figure>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting them all to the same width, but because their dimensions are different, they will have different heights. If you want them to be the same height, either crop them to the same dimensions, or warp them by setting a height. Your current `height: auto` just keeps their same dimensions.

```
By the way, nice banana.
```

Comment: *a research project on banana's abnormalities!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
...

.my-gallery img {
  ...
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.my-gallery figure {
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
...
```

Note:- But this will crop the image on right. So that is the decision you have to make how you want it.